# Can I fake/mock the type of my mock objects in python unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

In my python code I check the type of one of the parameters to make sure it is of the type I expect. For instance:

```
def myfunction(dbConnection):
    if (type(dbConnection)<>bpgsql.Connection):
        r['error'] += ' invalid database connection'
```

I want to pass a mock connection for testing purposes. Is there a way to make the mock object pretend to be of the correct type?

Comment: Use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) instead of relying on exact class names.

Comment: My first reaction: *Ick*! :-) I'd use `not isinstance(dbConnection, bpgsql.Connection)`, although [duck typing](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/duck_typing.shtml) would avoid your problem altogether.

Comment: So basically the answer is NO, you can't fake your type, instead don't check the type directly, see if it walks like a duck and if it is then it's good enough, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks but why isinstance is better than <> ?

Comment: @Ali `isinstance(x, Foo)` returns true if `x` is a `Foo`, including if `x` is an instance of a subclass of `Foo`.

Comment: Exactly. You should never compare types directly. Not only does this prevent testing like this, it will cause problems if the same module is imported twice causing different class definitions for the same type that will compare unequal. Also <> is deprecated, use !=.

Comment: @Antimony: Importing the class definition twice won't create two different memory positions or something; Python is smarter than that and reuse the module.

Comment: @Martijn, it will in old versions of IDLE. This is something that actually happened to me once.

Comment: @Antimony: Don't confuse bugs in IDLE with how Python works generally then. :-)

Comment: A note for future readers, and possibly this warrants an edit, but `<>` is no longer a part of actively developed Python, as of July 2023. It is instead a historic alternate to `!=` (not equals). See this post for more context.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749121/what-does-mean-in-python

Answer (score 98, accepted):

With all due respect, It looks like you guys are not quite correct!

I can use duck typing as said, but there is a way to do what I intended to do in the first place:

from http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html

Mock objects that use a class or an instance as a `spec` or `spec_set` are able to pass isintance tests:

```
>>>
>>> mock = Mock(spec=SomeClass)
>>> isinstance(mock, SomeClass)
True
>>> mock = Mock(spec_set=SomeClass())
>>> isinstance(mock, SomeClass)
True
```

so my example code would be like:

```
m = mock.MagicMock(spec=bpgsql.Connection)
isinstance(m, bpgsql.Connection)
```

this returns True

All that said, I am not arguing for strict type checking in python, I say if you need to check it you can do it and it works with testing and mocking too.

Comment: Also, sometimes you just don't have control over how another library is doing things. If something external is checking the type, it is probably easiest to just use spec or at least set the mock's `__class__` equal to the correct type.

Comment: I tried this for PyCharm's static inspections but to no avail. Seems like it should work though; you can find the bug here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10477

Answer (score 4):

This is more-or-less exactly why you shouldn't enforce strict typechecking! You should remove that line from the code entirely.

If you don't want to do that, write an abstract base class with the properties you want to have (`.connect()`, `.cursor()`, ...?) and check `isinstance` of that.

<sub>Also `<>` has been obsolete for aaages. Use `!=`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, so may I ask what is `patch` for? I confess that I have not yet undertood what it does, but to me it looks like it impersonates a different class  http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#id4

Comment: 100% agree on isinstance() over direct typechecking