# What does `<>` mean in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, operators, python-2.x

I'm trying to use in Python 3.3 an old library (dating from 2003!). When I import it, Python throws me an error because there are `<>` signs in the source file, e.g.:

```
if (cnum < 1000 and nnum <> 1000 and ntext[-1] <> "s":
    ...
```

I guess it's a now-abandoned sign in the language.

What exactly does it mean, and which (more recent) sign should I replace it with?

Comment: I would like to note that it is clearly *not* a Python 3.3 library, but a Python 2.x library.

Comment: [`!=` can also be written `<>`, but this is an obsolete usage kept for backwards compatibility only. New code should always use `!=`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan In 3.x, that's not true. As noted in answers below, it's not just obsolete, it's not valid syntax at all.

Comment: Reminds me of comparisons in ML.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

It means not equal to. It was taken from `ABC` (python's predecessor) see [here](http://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Esteven/abc/qr.html#TESTS):

> `x < y, x <= y, x >= y, x > y, x = y, x <> y, 0 <= d < 10`
>
> Order tests (`<>` means *'not equals'*)

I believe `ABC` took it from Pascal, a language Guido began programming with.

It has now been removed in Python 3. Use `!=` instead. If you are **CRAZY** you can scrap `!=` and allow only `<>` in Py3K using [this easter egg](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0401/#official-acts-of-the-flufl):

```
>>> from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL
>>> 1 != 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1 != 2
       ^
SyntaxError: with Barry as BDFL, use '<>' instead of '!='
>>> 1 <> 2
True
```

Comment: the `__future__` import does *not* "get it back in Python3". It effectively *replaces* `!=`. After doing that import the expression `1 != 2` raises a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Actually, it's not historical. It was a 1st April joke. See [PEP-401](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0401/).

Comment: Just a link to a relevant question: [So what exactly does “from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL” do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4007289/1386111)

Comment: Importantly (as noted by [one of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26393379/95852) to Alvin Wong's link), the `__future__` import only "works" at the REPL, not in a script.

Answer (score 48):

It means NOT EQUAL, but it is deprecated, use `!=` instead.

Comment: More than deprecated: in Python 3, it is a syntax error, as the questioner discovered.

Comment: Why would somebody add -1 for an accepted question? Comment please, so I could fix the problem, if there is any..

Comment: @PeterVaro I upvoted yours, but in general (not in this case!) an answer being accepted is not a reason not to downvote it if the downvoter considers it bad and the accepting a bad desicion (again, which does not apply in this case).

Comment: That said, I as well would like to know the reason for the -1 in this case - the answer is perfectly valid and correct.

Comment: @glglgl I've experienced this myself - someone feels the question shouldn't have been asked, and punishes anyone who leaves an answer even if the answer is correct.  I don't believe in that myself, I reserve my downvotes for answers that are factually incorrect or actively harmful in some way.

Answer (score 18):

It's worth knowing that you can use Python itself to find documentation, even for punctuation mark operators that Google can't cope with.

```
>>> help("<>")
```

> ### Comparisons
>
> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority,
>   which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise
>   operation.  Also unlike C, expressions like `a < b < c` have the
>   interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:
>
> Comparisons yield boolean values: `True` or `False`.
>
> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is
>   equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated
>   only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x <
>   y` is found to be false).
>
> **The forms `<>` and `!=` are equivalent; for consistency with C,
>   `!=` is preferred; where `!=` is mentioned below `<>` is also
>   accepted.  The `<>` spelling is considered obsolescent.**

See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: This also appears in python 3 (well, something different for me). How strange. +1

Comment: This would be a great answer except that it appears it's as obsolete as the `<>` operator itself.  @TerryA I can no longer find that text in Python 3.8.6.

Answer (score 15):

It is an old way of specifying `!=`, that was removed in Python 3. A library old enough to use it likely runs into various *other* incompatibilities with Python 3 as well: it is probably a good idea to run it through [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html), which automatically changes this, among many other things.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!=` or `<>`. Both stands for not equal.

[Reference: Python language reference]
The comparison operators `<>` and `!=` are alternate spellings of the same operator. `!=` is the preferred spelling; `<>` is obsolescent.