# python comparison, something is going wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am testing on idle like below, but something is going wrong..

```
>>> print 1<>1
False    OK
>>> print  1<>0
True     OK
>>> print False | True
True     OK
>>> print False | 1<>0
True     OK
>>> print 1<>1 | 1<>0
False   WHY ???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the `|` *bitwise OR* operator. You are probably looking for the `or` operator instead. `or` is the *boolean OR* operator.

Note that `<>` is deprecated, you want to use `!=` really.

```
>>> 1 != 1
False
>>> 1 != 0
True
>>> False or True
True
>>> False or 1 != 0
True
>>> 1 != 1 or 1 != 0
True
```

In Python, the `bool()` type is a subclass of `int()`, with `True` equal to 1 and `False` equal to 0, thus using a bitwise operator on `True` and `False` has the same output as if these values were integers instead:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> 10 | True
11
```

but because `|` has a *higher* precedent than `!=` (or `<>`) it is executed *first*:

```
>>> 1 != (1 | 1) != 0
False
>>> (1 != 1) | (1 != 0)
True
```

`or` *short circuits*, it returns the first expression value that is boolean true-ish (non-empty for collections, non-zero for numeric values).

Comment: Easy to test this behavior with: 1<>0 | 2     versus    1<>0 | 1

Answer (score 2):

Your code is being interpreted as:

```
>>> print 1 <> (1 | 1) <> 0
False
```

This is because of the [order precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), well documented in the link provided.

Pretty much, the bitwise OR operator has a higher precedence than the not-equals operator `<>` (do note that this is deprecated, and thus does not exist in Python 3. Further reading can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16749121/1971805)). Hence, it is evaluated first, then the `<>`s are interpreted next.

Answer (score 1):

It's operator precedence related issue:

```
>>> (1<>1) | (1<>0)
True
```

`|` has a higher precedence than `<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Precedence. Your command is being interpreted as `1 <> (1 | 1) <> 0`

By the way, you should not use `<>` for comparisons. Use `!=` instead.

For more information, check the docs on [operators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).