# Use of <> in Python. Is <> an operator?

Tags: python

```
>>> 1<>1
False
>>> 1<>2
True
>>> 1<>3
True
>>> 1<>0
True
>>> 1<>1
False
```

What is the use of <> in Python?
Can someone help in explaining the above or the '<>' in general.

Comment: 'Not equal', since it logically equates to 'greater or less than'. As any real number is greater or less than a given number as long as its not equal to that given number. Also written as '!=' in other languages.

Comment: Without being a Python programmer: `<>` returns `False` if the arguments are equal, and `True` if they're not equal. At a trivial level, I can work out what that does. (It's also inherited from BASIC and probably some other older languages as well).

Comment: Dup: [What does `<>` mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749121/what-does-mean-in-python)

Comment: According to `ast.parse('1<>1')`, the `Expr`'s root value is an `Compare` operator whose op is `NotEq`. Which proves that the documentation is correct; `<>` is not-equals.

Comment: Also, Python's built-in help is helpful. `help('<>')` tells you the exact same thing that NPE found online

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the inequality operator, synonymous to `!=`. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> The forms `<>` and `!=` are equivalent; for consistency with C, `!=` is preferred; where `!=` is mentioned below `<>` is also accepted. The `<>` spelling is considered obsolescent.

The `<>` spelling has been removed in Python 3.

Comment: "The `<>` spelling has been removed in Python 3." Not quite true. `from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL` although doing this `!=` will raise a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like it's the same as !=