# When to use `<>` and `!=` operators?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, comparison-operators, python-internals

Couldn't find much on this. Trying to compare 2 values, but they can't be equal. In my case, they can be (and often are) either greater than or less than.

Should I use:

```
if a <> b:
   dostuff
```

or

```
if a != b:
   dostuff
```

[This page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/comparison_operators_example.htm) says they're similar, which implies there's at least something different about them.

Comment: Don't know how in Python exactly, but I feel <> should be use for numbers only (not for comapring strings), != for both.

Comment: Well I think `<>` would take two compression first `a>b` and `a<b` and if both are false it will be True for equality. But `!=` case there would be only one comparison i.e. not equal.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. in my case, `a` and `b` are both numbers. Both can be null, so <> makes the most sense because I don't care about `b` if it's null.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749121/what-does-mean-in-python/16749135#16749135

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quoting from [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators),

> The comparison operators `<>` and `!=` are alternate spellings of the same operator. `!=` is the preferred spelling; `<>` is obsolescent.

So, they both are one and the same, but `!=` is preferred over `<>`.

I tried disassembling the code in Python 2.7.8

```
from dis import dis
form_1 = compile("'Python' <> 'Python'", "string", 'exec')
form_2 = compile("'Python' != 'Python'", "string", 'exec')
dis(form_1)
dis(form_2)
```

And got the following

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Python')
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Python')
              6 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE

  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Python')
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Python')
              6 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Both `<>` and `!=` are generating the same byte code

```
              6 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
```

So they both are one and the same.

### Note:

`<>` is removed in Python 3.x, as per [the Python 3 Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators).

Quoting [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons),

> `!=` can also be written `<>`, but this is an obsolete usage kept for backwards compatibility only. **New code should always use `!=`**.

**Conclusion**

Since `<>` is removed in 3.x, and as per the documentation, `!=` is the preferred way, better don't use `<>` at all.

Comment: Ok, but what if `b` can't be null? using `<>` sounds to me like both variables must have a value

Comment: @JeremyDavis As mentioned in the official documentation, `<>` is another way to say `!=`. So there is absolutely no difference between `<>` and `!=`. But we should prefer `!=`.

Comment: @JeremyDavis Please check the included disassembled byte codes for the confirmation.

Comment: Both variables must have a value either way, or you get a NameError before the operator is evaluated (meaning a variable didn't exist, not that it is null). Python doesn't have null; None is just a value which is unequal to other values.

Comment: Commendable effort put into this answer. However the brief answer is just never use `<>`

Answer (score 0):

Just stick to `!=`.

`<>` is outdated! Please check recent python reference manual.