# Convert pascal to python

Tags: python

I have the following Pascal routine:

```
function TForm1.ldExtractFromLine (ldline: String; Post: Integer): String;
var
  s: String;
  t: array[1..15] of String;
  i, iT: Integer;
begin
  s := Trim(ldline);
  iT := 1;
  while s <> '' do
  begin
    s := Trim(s) + ' ';
    i := 1;
    while s[i] <> ' ' do Inc(i);
    t[iT] := Copy(s, 1, i-1);
    Inc(iT);
    s := Copy(s, i, Length(s));
  end;
  ldExtractFromLine := '';
  if Post < iT then ldExtractFromLine := t[Post];
end;
```

I am trying to convert to Python. Here is what I have so far:

```
def ldExtractFromLine (ldline, post):
    post -= 1    # mjh
    t = []

    s = ldline.strip()
    iT = 0;    # mjh
    while s <> '':
        s = s.strip() + ' '
        i = 0    # mjh
        while s[i] <> ' ': i += 1
#         t[iT] = Copy(s, 1, i-1)
#         function Copy(const S: string; From: integer = 1; Count: integer = MaxInt): string;
        t.insert(iT, s[0:i-1+1])    # mjh
        iT += 1
        s = s[i:(i+len(s)+1)]
        print "lala"

    result = ''
    if post < iT: result = t[post]    # mjh
    return result
```

However, executing the routine results in endless "lala" printed to stdout. The problem is that Pascal lists start with index 1 and Python lists start with index 0. This is really confusing me. Can anyone find my error? The variable `post` is an integer generally less than 20. The variable `ldline` is a string that looks somewhat like "1 0 60 -24 -160 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3001.dat".

[edit]

The entire script can be viewed here:

https://github.com/Jeremy1980/LDBoxer

Here is some example input data:

```
0 Safe House
0 Name: building_013_safehouse.ldr
0 Author: Kevin Loch
0 ROTATION CENTER 0 0 0 1 "Custom"
0 ROTATION CONFIG 0 0
1 0 60 -24 -160 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3001.dat
1 0 60 -24 -160 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3001.dat
1 0 -20 -24 -160 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3001.dat
1 0 -20 -24 -160 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3001.dat
1 0 -100 -24 -160 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3001.dat
1 0 -100 -24 -160 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3001.dat
1 0 -180 -24 -160 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3001.dat
1 0 -180 -24 -160 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3001.dat
```

More examples of input data can be found here:

https://github.com/Jeremy1980/LDBoxer/issues/4

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What is a correct result?

Comment: The `<>` looks at least marginal, if not exactly wrong.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749121/what-does-mean-in-python

Comment: Are you actually attempting to split the string on spaces? `ldline.split()` does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in your code is in the line:

```
s = s[i:(i+len(s)+1)]
```

You leave a leading space in the string `s` that leads to an infinite loop and `(i+len(s)+1)` part is wrong. It could be replaced with:

```
s = s[i+1:]
```

In general, this pascal function simply splits the string and gets `Post`-th element (1-based). The equivalent is something like this:

```
def ldExtractFromLine (ldline, post):
    a = ldline.split()
    if post <= len(a):
        return a[post-1]
    return ''
```

Comment: No need really to define a function if `ldline.split()[post-1]` does what you need. The program should perhaps split the `ldline` just once and keep the values in an array if it needs to extract multiple posts, but we of course do not know if this refactoring is feasible or necessary.