# Updating a pandas column to replace values with np.nan if the value occurs once, and then reset once another value occus

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x

The title is very confusing, so let me explain. I have a pandas column:

```
x   | desired x
1.5 | 1
1   | 1
1   | 1         
1   | 1
1   | 1
0   | 0
0   | 0
0   | 0
0   | 0
1   | 0
0   | 0
-1.5|-1
-1  |-1
-1  |-1
-1  |-1
0   | 0  
0   | 0
0   | 0
0   | 0
-1  | 0
0   | 0
0   | 0
1.5 | 1
```

...

Currently, I have solved this using itertuples:

```
 currval = np.nan
for idx in df.itertuples():
    if idx[33] == 1.5: 
        currval = 1
    elif idx[33] == -1.5:
        currval = -1
    elif idx[32] <> "":
        currval = np.nan
    else: 
        next
    df.loc[idx.Index,'refPos2'] = currval
```

however, this code is wayyyyyy too slow, and was wondering if anyone had ideas on how to vectorize this.

Thanks!

Comment: they are just columns in the data frame that I am working with. Idx is the row iteration. If it helps, 32 is an indicator column named exit and 33 is an indicator column named 'refPos'

Comment: no, it is simply just to pass to the next iteration

Comment: It will work but that wont do what you are expecting. I think you need to use pass instead of next. [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) is a built-in function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749121/what-does-mean-in-python, <> is not equal to

Comment: I have deleted previous comments, these are getting too big. `<>` is deprecated for a long time, `next` doesn't do what you want and your question is unclear. It seems easily vectorizble, but you really really should put some more effort explaining what you're doing.

Comment: Excuse me, So i currently have a list, let's say column x, the column has 5 unique values, -1.5,1.5,1,-1,and 0. -1.5 and 1.5 occur once, followed by a random amount of 1's and -1's followed by a mix of 0's and 1's or 0's and -1's. I need this new list to basically search for 1.5/-1.5, set them equal to 1/-1 respectively and then check for the first 0 after that -1.5/1.5 and replace all values after the first 0 with 0 until the next 1.5/-1.5 when this sequence within the list starts over again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement I understood from the comments, here is the solution:

```
for index, item in enumerate(a): ## a is your list [-1.5,1,1,0,1,1.5]
    if item == 1.5:
       a[index] = 1
    elif item == -1.5:
       a[index] = -1
    elif a[index] == 0:
        a[index] = 0
    elif a[index] == 1 and a[index-1] ==0:
        a[index] = 0
    else:
        a[index] =1
```

Comment: close, not entirely correct but that is my fault for explaining it poorly; in addition, I need to have a vectorized solution or a solution aster than a for loop.

Comment: the third elif would be: "elif (a[index] == 1 or a[index] == -1) and a[index-1] == 0:", and the last else would be either -1 or 1 depending on if the previous value was -1 or 1 respectively

Comment: Yes!! I missed the `-1` part!! What I would suggest is "Ask a new question suggesting that this can be done by loop thro' my solution and now what to vectorize it.

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted, but am too new for my vote to display in the public!

Comment: No problem, if you get an other answers then good, otherwise implement my advice, even if you can't explain well enough what you need. folks would understand from code I wrote...and then you can accept my answer for this solution!!