# Mocking datetime: isinstance() fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, datetime, mocking

Mocking `datetime` does not work this way:

```
import mock
import datetime

with mock.patch('datetime.datetime', mock.Mock(wraps=datetime.datetime)) as datetime_mock:
    datetime_mock.now.return_value = datetime.datetime(1968, 8, 17)
    assert isinstance(datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1), datetime.datetime)
```

Exception:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

Has someone a solution to make the `isinstance()` call work for the mocked object?

**Update**

The `isinstance()` call does not happen in my code space. It happens in an external library. Answers like "don't use isinstance()" won't help.

**Update 2**

Python 2.7 and mock==1.0.1

Comment: But you mocked `datetime.datetime`, so that's a Mock *instance* now. Why are you trying to use `isinstance()` *in the first place*?

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe of: [Can I fake/mock the type of my mock objects in python unittests](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11282401)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I updated the question: the isinstance() call does not happen in my code space. It happens in an external library. Answers like "don't use isinstance()" won't help.

Comment: Did you read the answer marked as accepted? It is a self-answer, so sorted below the glib 'do not use `isinstance()`' post, and shows how you need to use `spec`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried it with spec, wraps and both. Some result: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types. I updated my version info.