# Python Compare MagicMock.__int__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unit-testing, pytest

I am learning about using MagicMock and pytest for test python function and I found case that I have to convert MagicMock to Int and then compare to number again

I have function do something like this

```
def func(x)​:
     if int(x)​ > 5 :
          return True
     else :
          return False
```

and I want to test this function so I do this

```
def test_func()​:
     int_mock = MagicMock() 
     int_mock.__gt__.return_value = True
     input_mock = MagicMock()
     input_mock.__int__.return_value = int_mock
     assert func()​
```

but problem is **int** must return int

So how to test it it correct way

I want to test this without assume any number like 6 or 0 for make my test pass

Comment: You don't need any mock to test this function - just test the functionality as usual.

Comment: To elaborate: you are trying to test the internal implementation of the function instead of the function itself. You should test the input/output for typical and edge values, as usual, so that a changed implementation does not invalidate your tests (e.g. if the function was rewritten like `return not int(x) < 6` your tests would fail). Generally, it is rarely a good idea to mock an operator function.

Comment: Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920344/is-it-possible-to-mock-the-builtin-len-function-in-python-3-6) that may help you!