# How can I mock patch a class used in an isinstance test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I want to test the function `is_myclass`. Please help me understand how to write a successful test.

```
def is_myclass(obj):
    """This absurd stub is a simplified version of the production code."""
    isinstance(obj, MyClass)
    MyClass()
```

**Docs**

The Python Docs for unittest.mock illustrate three ways of addressing the `isinstance` problem:

- Set the `spec` parameter to the real class.
- Assign the real class to the `__class__` attribute.
- Use `spec` in the patch of the real class.

> `__class__`
>
> Normally the `__class__` attribute of an object will return its type. For a mock object with a spec, `__class__` returns the spec class instead. This allows mock objects to pass isinstance() tests for the object they are replacing / masquerading as:
>
> ```
> >>> mock = Mock(spec=3)
> >>> isinstance(mock, int)
> True
> ```
>
> `__class__` is assignable to, this allows a mock to pass an `isinstance()` check without forcing you to use a spec:
>
> ```
> >>> mock = Mock()
> >>> mock.__class__ = dict
> >>> isinstance(mock, dict)
> True
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> If you use `spec` or `spec_set` and `patch()` is replacing a class, then the return value of the created mock will have the same spec.
>
> ```
> >>> Original = Class
> >>> patcher = patch('__main__.Class', spec=True)
> >>> MockClass = patcher.start()
> >>> instance = MockClass()
> >>> assert isinstance(instance, Original)
> >>> patcher.stop()
> ```

**Tests**

I have written five tests each of which attempts firstly to reproduce each of the three solutions and secondly to carry out a realistic test of the target code. The typical pattern is  `assert isinstance`  followed by a call to `is_myclass`.

All tests fail.

**Test 1**

This is a close copy of the example provided in the docs for the use of `spec`. It
differs from the docs by using `spec=<class>` instead of `spec=<instance>`. It passes
a local assert test but the call to `is_myclass` fails because `MyClass` is not mocked.

This is equivalent to Michele d’Amico’s answer to the similar question in [isinstance and Mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146725/isinstance-and-mocking) .

**Test 2**

This is the patched equivalent of test 1. The `spec` argument fails to set the `__class__` of the mocked MyClass and the test fails the local `assert isinstance`.

**Test 3**

This is a close copy of the example provided in the docs for the use of `__class__`. It passes
a local assert test but the call to `is_myclass` fails because `MyClass` is not mocked.

**Test 4**

This is the patched equivalent of test 3. The assignment to `__class__` does set the `__class__` of the mocked `MyClass` but this does not change its type and so the test fails the local `assert isinstance`.

**Test 5**

This is a close copy of the use of `spec` in a call to patch. It passes the local assert test but only by virtue of accessing a local copy of MyClass. Since this local variable is not used within `is_myclass` the call fails.

**Code**

*This code was written as a stand alone test module intended to be run in the PyCharm IDE. You may need to modify it to run in other test environments.*

module temp2.py

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock


class WrongCodeTested(Exception):
    pass


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        """This is a simplified version of a production class which must be mocked for unittesting."""
        raise WrongCodeTested('Testing code in MyClass.__init__')


def is_myclass(obj):
    """This absurd stub is a simplified version of the production code."""
    isinstance(obj, MyClass)
    MyClass()


class ExamplesFromDocs(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1_spec(self):
        obj = mock.Mock(spec=MyClass)
        print(type(MyClass))  # <class 'type'>
        assert isinstance(obj, MyClass)  # Local assert test passes
        is_myclass(obj)  # Fail: MyClass instantiated


    def test_2_spec_patch(self):
        with mock.patch('temp2.MyClass', spec=True) as mock_myclass:
            obj = mock_myclass()
            print(type(mock_myclass))  # <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
            print(type(MyClass))  # <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
            assert isinstance(obj, MyClass)  # Local assert test fails

    def test_3__class__(self):
        obj = mock.Mock()
        obj.__class__ = MyClass
        print(type(MyClass))  # <class 'type'>
        isinstance(obj, MyClass)  # Local assert test passes
        is_myclass(obj)  # Fail: MyClass instantiated

    def test_4__class__patch(self):
        Original = MyClass
        with mock.patch('temp2.MyClass') as mock_myclass:
            mock_myclass.__class__ = Original
            obj = mock_myclass()
            obj.__class__ = Original
            print(MyClass.__class__)  # <class 'temp2.MyClass'>
            print(type(MyClass))  # <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
            assert isinstance(obj, MyClass)  # Local assert test fails

    def test_5_patch_with_spec(self):
        Original = MyClass
        p = mock.patch('temp2.MyClass', spec=True)
        MockMyClass = p.start()
        obj = MockMyClass()
        print(type(Original))  # <class 'type'>
        print(type(MyClass))  # <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
        print(type(MockMyClass))  # <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
        assert isinstance(obj, Original)  # Local assert test passes
        is_myclass(obj)  # Fail: Bad type for MyClass
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't mock the second argument of `isinstance()`, no. The documentation you found concerns making a mock as the *first* argument pass the test. If you want to produce something that is acceptable as the second argument to `isinstance()`, you actually have to have a *type*, not an instance (and mocks are always instances).

You could use a subclass instead of `MyClass` instead, that'll definitely pass, and giving it a `__new__` method lets you alter what is returned when you try to call it to create an instance:

```
class MockedSubClass(MyClass):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return mock.Mock(spec=cls)  # produce a mocked instance when called
```

and patch that in:

```
mock.patch('temp2.MyClass', new=MockedSubClass)
```

and use an instance of that class as the mock:

```
instance = mock.Mock(spec=MockedSubClass)
```

Or, and this is *much simpler*, just use `Mock` as the class, and have `obj` be an `Mock` instance:

```
with mock.patch('temp2.MyClass', new=mock.Mock) as mocked_class:
    is_myclass(mocked_class())
```

Either way, your test then passes:

```
>>> with mock.patch('temp2.MyClass', new=MockedSubClass) as mocked_class:
...     instance = mock.Mock(spec=MockedSubClass)
...     assert isinstance(instance, mocked_class)
...     is_myclass(instance)
...
>>> # no exceptions raised!
...
>>> with mock.patch('temp2.MyClass', new=mock.Mock) as mocked_class:
...     is_myclass(mocked_class())
...
>>> # no exceptions raised!
...
```

---

For your specific tests, here is why they fail:

1. You never mocked `MyClass`, it still references the original class. The first line of `is_myclass()` succeeds, but the second line uses the original `MyClass` and it is booby trapped.
2. `MyClass` is replaced with a `mock.Mock` instance, not an actual type, so `isinstance()` raises a `TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types` exception.
3. Fails exactly the same way 1 failed, `MyClass` is left in-tact and is booby trapped.
4. Fails the same way as 2 does. `__class__` is an attribute only useful on *instances*. A class object doesn't use the `__class__` attribute, you still have an instance instead of a class and `isinstance()` raises a type error.
5. is essentially exactly the same as 4, only you started the patcher manually instead of having the context manager take care of it, and you used `isinstance(obj, Original)` to check the instance, so you never got the type error there. The type error is instead triggered in `is_myclass()`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your simpler solution was not available for my production code because I needed to access "mockedclass()" outside the scope of the context manager.

Comment: It should also be noted that each call to mocked class() will create new mock objects which *will not* compare equal. If equality is required then MockedSubClass has to be implemented as a singleton. 
This would be the case where an object is instantiated in the test code and there is a need to ensure that it has been correctly instantiated by comparing it with a separately created test object.

Comment: @lemi57ssss yes, right now the `__new__` implementation is the simplest version needed to make the example in your question work. If there are additional requirements, adjust what “instance” calling the class produces to meet those requirements.

Comment: The simple solution here is great. In my case I subclassed `mock.Mock` as `SubMock` so that its `__init__` (which must call `super().__init__()`) then added a couple of necessary attributes, putting `..., new=SubMock) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can use auto_spec on a mocked class and still be able to call `isinstance`.

```py
def get_mock_ability_class():

    class MockAbility(Ability):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            return mock.create_autospec(MockAbility, *args, **kwargs)
    return MockAbility

MockAbility = get_mock_ability_class()
AnotherMockAbility = get_mock_ability_class()

m = MockAbility()
a = AnotherMockAbility()
isinstance(m, MockAbility)  # True
isinstance(a, MockAbility)  # False

# Ability has a forget method
m.forget()
m.forget.assert_called_once()
```

*credit to Perry Goy for coming up with this*

Answer (score 0):

@Martijn Pieters has an excellent answer, I just thought I'd add how I accomplished this with decoraters:

```
import temp2

class MockedMyClass:
    pass

class MockedMySubClass(MockedMyClass):
    pass

@patch("temp2.MyClass", new=MockedMyClass)
def test_is_subclass(self):
    assert issubclass(MockedMySubClass, temp2.MyClass)
```

**NOTE:** Even though a decorator is used, the test does not require any additional arguments.