# How to patch datetime.datetime.now() so it passes isinstance test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, datetime, mocking

I've patched `datetime.datetime` with `MagicMock` using the `spec` parameter.

```
patch(
  'datetime.datetime',
  MagicMock(spec=datetime, now=lambda: datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=61)):
     action_involving_datetime.now()
```

Yet a `isinstance(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime)` fails with:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Because `datetime.datetime` still returns the `MagicMock` class. Any ideas?

Comment: Not closing the question as it's not an exact duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146725/isinstance-and-mocking

Comment: @Selcuk But the answer is saying I should use spec, and I do use spec.

Comment: Why did you patched the `datetime.datetime` instead of `your_module.datetime.datetime.now`?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi You're suggesting I should provision my own datetime type? I think this would still make the `isinstance` test fail

Comment: Take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/maurobaraldi/266435b877f6dd342b19280cdee8908e#file-mocks_for_humans-html-L319-L339) and see if it help. PS: the presentation is in portuguese...