# How to fool issubclass checks with a MagicMock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, subclass, python-unittest.mock

I have something like this:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

mock_B = MagicMock(spec_set=B)
assert issubclass(mock_B, A)  # TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

How can I get this to pass?

[isinstance and Mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146725/isinstance-and-mocking) had a lot of stuff various answers, but from there I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you want to treat `mock_B`, an instance of `MagicMock`, as a class, but an object in Python can only be considered as a class if it is an instance of `type`, which `mock_B` is simply not.

So instead of trying to make a `Mock` object class-like, which is technically impossible since Python does not allow dynamically changing the type of an object, a workaround would be to make a class `Mock`-like. To do that, we can create a class with the same name and base classes as the class you want to mock, but then delegate all of its attribute lookups to a `Mock` object by making the [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) method of the class' [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) perform such a delegation. This way, the new class passes the `issubclass` check easily because it is really a subclass of the intended base class `A`, and yet it also behaves like a `Mock` object because all attribute lookups are delegated to one.

However, one problem with delegating all attribute lookups to a `Mock` object is that the resulting "class" would not behave like a class as the `Mock` object has no class-like attributes. We can solve this by defaulting attributes that aren't available in the `Mock` object to the class being mocked instead:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def mock_class(cls):
    class meta(type):
        def __getattribute__(self, name):
            try:
                return getattr(mock, name)
            except AttributeError:
                return getattr(cls, name)

    mock = MagicMock(spec_set=cls)
    return meta(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, {})
```

so that:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        pass

mock_B = mock_class(B)
assert issubclass(mock_B, A)
print(mock_B)
print(mock_B.foo)
print(mock_B.__name__)
print(mock_B.__bases__)
```

passes the `issubclass` assertion and outputs:

```
<class '__main__.B'>
<MagicMock name='mock.foo' id='1970990059024'>
B
(<class '__main__.A'>,)
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVG7boQwEOz9FS6NhK5JE0W6AqSU9w0WOMvFCmBrvUiHonw7WT9QICmyjdnx7Hhn8Cu9u/np2eO2DegmucyWCAJdJmc@pJ28Q5K37m7NjQEh3mCQ8UqbsQtBmTFUL0JypV5OQJ2i1UNBY8URre98Q4S2Xwi0VgHGoZZzNx2ZsQjXMxALgRacZdFQcYEyfKLCw4An2ezvvCI6/FeNPexiiZqcX39Mq@DB6AB0jW7FQSG5ZfCidZzXupa567sAIbafXyyao2nyIp6/d6hVTXEfMxqcS7EcAsnklHfLKx2CbyvBB/DPsSEsfQYzsZZNJTzamQpw7i78zi9kX/8PXHxU2/YN)